# 集合当てクイズの解法

Tags: アルゴリズム

次のようなゲームを考えます。

アルファベット 'A'~'Z'を全体集合とし、その部分集合が一つ与えられているとします。これを答えと呼びます。
プレイヤーは1ターンにつき次の問い合わせを一回出来ます。

問い合わせ：アルファベット'A'~'Z'の集合を一つ入力とし、答えと入力の積集合が空集合であるか否かがYes/Noで返ってくる。

これで答えが確定するまでのターン数を競います。

プレイヤーの最善戦略はどのようなものになるでしょうか？
またプレイヤーが最善戦略をとった時の最悪のターン数は何ターンでしょうか？

なお、ターン数の平均値が最も低い戦略を最善の戦略と呼ぶことにします。

Answer (score 0):

アルファベット何個が含まれているかは任意であるなら解は `2**26` 通りで、なおかつこの条件だと順序付けが困難なので二分法による探索ができない、ということになります。だからプレイヤー側の最善戦略っつか唯一の戦略は１文字づつ総当たり探索する、つまり

- 部分集合 'A' に対してクエリする ... 'A' が含まれているかがわかる
- 部分集合 'B' に対してクエリする ... 'B' が含まれているかがわかる
- 部分集合 'Z' に対してクエリする ... 'Z' が含まれているかがわかる

で 26 回のクエリで正解に達することができる（最悪＝最善＝平均）でしょう。

---

正解に含まれている文字が任意個数である以上、１文字でないクエリをすると（例えば `AB` と `AC` と `ADE` ) これらすべての結果が「含まれている」である場合 `A` が含まれているか否かは不明なわけです。であれば２文字以上のクエリを行うことは無駄であると導けます。

Comment: 一文字づつ調べる戦略に比べて、他の戦略をとった時に、ターンの平均値がどうしても上がってしまうということは示せないでしょうか？

Comment: あ～でもなんか一文字づつ調べるのが最善のような気がしてきました。

Comment: 一応、直観では一文字づつ調べるのが最善とは思うのですが、例えば{A,B,C}を問い合わせて、いづれも答えに含まれないなら3文字まとめて候補から消せます。どのような工夫をしてもうまい手が絶対ないことを納得できるうまい理屈はないでしょうか

Comment: その三つのそれぞれ文字が含まれる確率が1/2として試行回数の期待値を求めたらどうですか？

Comment: 1*1/8+4*7/8=3.625でしょうか？確かに期待値増えてますね。。。

Comment: ライアーゲームみたいに対人戦でオイラが出題側なら、その程度で簡単に除外できないようアルファベット文字25個を答えとしますね

Comment: 脇道にそれますが、これ例えば問い合わせを集合のサイズ３以上とかに制限したらめちゃくちゃ難しくなったりするんですかね？

Comment: サイズ３以上に制限したら答えを決定できない可能性があるのか。難しいですね、、、

Comment: 問い合わせの集合がすべて答えに含まれる場合、大当たりと答えが返ってくるとか、色々派生問題が考えられますね。脇道ですが。

Comment: アルファベット順に3文字づつ問い合わせるとして、最短のターン数は問い合わせの結果が空集合ではない場合が1回の場合で、9回+(3回*1セット) = 12回(端数があるので11回の場合もあり得ます)、最長のターン数は全ての問い合わせの結果が空集合ではない場合で 9回+(3回*9セット) = 36回になるので、平均のターン数は `(∑(9+3n){n=1,9})/9 = 24` ……になる様な気が…はて…？

Comment: 場合の数の数え方が多分間違ってますね。

Answer (score 0):

一応自分なりの結論としては、一文字づつ調べるのが最善です。

初期状態として解の候補が2**26あります。
そして問い合わせをするたびにyes/noが返ってくるのでその実行過程は2分木としてあらわされます。
そして解の候補が1つになった時に葉となります。

2分木の最も効率の良いのは完全2分木ですが、一文字づつ調べる戦略はまさに完全2分木になります。
よって一文字づづ調べるのが最善と思われます。